# How do I access the Options Object in Services.Configure<MyOptions> in DotNet Core Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am relatively new to dependency injections. I have the following code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
               .UseConsoleLifetime()
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   services.AddFtpServer(opt => opt.UseDotNetFileSystem()).AddHostedService<HostedFtpService>();
                   services.AddSingleton<IMembershipProvider, CustomMembershipProvider>();
                   services.Configure<FtpServerOptions>(opt => opt.Port = 33999);
                });
            var host = hostBuilder.Build();

            var Item1 = host.Services.GetService<IMembershipProvider>(); //This works, I can get the new CustomMembershipProvider Object
            var Item2 = host.Services.GetService<FtpServerOptions>(); //This does NOT work....


        }
```

I can access the **CustomMembershipProvider** object, but...

### How do I access the **FtpServerOptions** object?

Below is the FtpServerOptions class

```
public class FtpServerOptions
        {
            public string? ServerAddress { get; set; }
            public int Port { get; set; } = 21;
            public int MaxActiveConnections { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan? ConnectionInactivityCheckInterval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this :

```
var Item2 = host.Services.GetService<IOptions<FtpServerOptions>>();
```

And Get the FtpServerOptions:

```
var  options = Item2.Value
```

Comment: Cool it works, but there is also IOptionsMonitor which is probably the one i need. Thanks!